# Equality or inequality for determinant of $A_{n \times m} D_{m \times m} A^T_{m \times n}$

Tags: determinants, matrix-theory, decomposition-theorem

Assume that we have a matrix product of form $B=A_{n \times m} D_{m \times m} A^T_{m \times n}$. $D$ is a positive diagonal matrix and $m > n$.

Is there any equality or inequality over $|B|$, $|AA^T|$ and $|D|$ or their logarithms.

Comment: What do you mean by "invequality over"? Do you mean "inequality for $\det(B)$ *in terms of* $\det(AA^T)$, $\det(D)$, and logarithms thereof?" Also, is there any *reason* why you suspect that logarithms of determinants play any meaningful role? (That seems unusual to me.)

Comment: Exactly I mean the inequality you mentioned. In my problem determinants of $AA^T$ and $D$ or their logarithms are given, but I need determinant of $B$.

Comment: Would you mind to state what exactly "is given" in you problem, please?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is, using exterior product as a functor: Let $e_i$ be the basis of $\mathbb R^n$. Then 
\begin{align}
\det(A.D.A^\top)e_1\wedge\dots\wedge e_n &= \Lambda^n(A.D.A^\top)(e_1\wedge\dots\wedge e_n)
\\&
=\Lambda^n(A).\Lambda^n(D).\Lambda^n(A^\top)(e_1\wedge\dots\wedge e_n)
\end{align}
Note that $\Lambda^n(A)$ is a $\binom mn$ covector of signed determinants of $n\times n$ minors of $A$, and $\Lambda^n(A^\top)$ is its transpose, a column vector. See [Greub: Multilinear Algebra].

Comment: Thanks Peter Michor for your reply. What do you mean by "covector of signed determinants"?