# $A_{n \times m} D_{m \times m} A^T_{m \times n} + \alpha I_{n \times n}$

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, determinants, matrix-theory

Assume that we have a matrix product of form $B=A_{n \times m} D_{m \times m} A^T_{m \times n} + \alpha I_{n \times n}$. $D$ is a positive diagonal matrix, $I$ is identity matrix, $\alpha>0$ and $m < n$.

Is there any relation between  $|B|$, $|AA^T|$, $|D|$ and $|I|$ or their logarithms, in the form of an equality or an inequality?

Comment: This is a near-duplicate of: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293103/equality-or-inequality-for-determinant-of-a-n-times-m-d-m-times-m-at-m

Comment: I think that this is not a near-duplicate because these are two different cases. Here $m<n$ and $\alpha$ is positive (not zero). It seems that suggestions for two cases will be distinct.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\det(A.D.A^\top + \alpha I) &= \sum_{k=0}^n \alpha^{n-k} \text{Trace}(\Lambda^k(A.D.A^\top)) 
\\&
= \sum_{k=0}^n \alpha^{n-k} \text{Trace}\big(\Lambda^k(A).\Lambda^k(D).\Lambda^k(A^\top)\big)
\end{align}